# Dynamically loading html with jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, jquery

I'm running into a bit of an issue with this site I am currently building, I am using jQuery's .load() to grab an html file and include it in the #content of my site

`<a href="#" onclick="$('#content').load('port/1.html')">1</a>`

The chunk of code that is being pulled in has a jQuery click function on a few thumbnail images..

```
<div id="bigImg"><img src="images/1large.jpg" alt="Large View" id="lrg" /></div>
<div id="thumbCont">
<div class="thumb first"><img src="images/thumb1.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 1" data-lrg="images/1large.jpg" class="th"></div>
<div class="thumb"><img src="images/thumb2.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 2" data-lrg="images/2large.jpg" class="th"></div>
<div class="thumb"><img src="images/thumb3.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 3" data-lrg="images/3large.jpg" class="th"></div>
<div class="thumb"><img src="images/thumb4.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 5" data-lrg="images/4large.jpg" class="th"></div>
<div class="thumb last"><img src="images/thumb5.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 5" data-lrg="images/5large.jpg" class="th"></div>
</div>
```

and here is the jQuery to swap the images..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img.th').click(function(){
        lrg = $(this).attr('data-lrg');
        olrg = $('#lrg');
        if (lrg != olrg.attr('src')) {
            olrg.fadeOut('normal',function(){olrg.attr('src',lrg)});
            olrg.fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

So when the user clicks on the image, jquery pulls the new image src from data-lrg. This function works great, until I decided to pull the html with jquery instead of php.

Any idea why jQuery would not recognize the new html?

My thoughts:
I'm guessing it has something to do with jQuery setting up shop before this part of the page is loaded, which tells me that I need to figure out a way to tell jQuery to look at this section again, or look at the whole page again.... but I am at a loss on how to do that.

(I know the onclick isn't the best way to do it, but it makes it easy for early development)

Comment: Have tested with simple html pages and is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.delegate` tends to be preferred in favour of `$.live`. You can delegate the event listener from a parent element, and this will respect all current and future child elements:

```
$('#thumbCont').delegate('img.th', 'click', function(e) {
  // ...
});
```

**Edit**

A little more detail on the differences between `delegate` and `live`:

They behave in a similar way, but `delegate` tends to outperform `live`; it would be going a bit far to suggest that `live` is deprecated as so much code relies on it, but `delegate` was introduced in 1.4 to address some of the pitfalls of `live` (introduced in 1.3). Basically, `live` attaches an event listener to the `document`, whereas `delegate` attaches it to the selector passed to your jQuery method. There are fewer chances for unintended collisions, it performs better, as it only has to traverse a small subset of elements, and there are some side-issues with chaining that `live` struggles with ([more here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-the-difference-between-live-and-delegate/)).

Comment: Well I wasn' aware of that. You learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
$('img.th').live('click', function(){...});
```

That way the click action is attached to any current and future img.th selectors.

Answer (score 4):

You need to attach the event handlers after you have loaded the html.

Or you can use .live()